# The onclick function is not working in IE but works fine on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to open a div on click of an image, so for this I simply created an `onclick` event for a function within image tag.
When I click on the image it shows that `'the function is undefined'`. The same code works fine on other browsers but not on IE.
I really need help on this. Tried multiple things with reference to the similar questions asked here but nothing seems working. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code I tried

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-bubble" id="chat-bubble">
   <div id="chat-header">
      <img src="images/Chatbot-icon.png" id="chat-icon" /><span> YODA </span
      ><img
         src="images/close.png"
         id="close-icon"
         onclick="closeFunction()"
      />
   </div>
   <div id="webchat" role="main" class="webchat"></div>
   <div id="botchat" role="main" class="webchat"></div>
   <img
      src="images/Chatbot-icon.png"
      id="chatBubble"
      onClick="javascript: myFunction();"
   /><img
      src="images/Chatbot-icon.png"
      id="Bubble"
      onmousedown="myChat();"
   />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function myChat() {
   var a = document.getElementById("botchat");

   var b = document.getElementById("chat-header");

   var c = document.getElementById("body");
   document.getElementById("Bubble").style.display = "none";
   if (a.style.display == "block") {
      a.style.display = "none";
   } else {
      a.style.display = "block";
   }
   if (b.style.display == "block") {
      b.style.display = "none";
   } else {
      b.style.display = "block";
   }
   c.style.height = "100vh";
   c.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: I need to get this code working on IE

Comment: Javascript, like other languages, is a language.  And run on sentences are always hard to read.  Please format your code.

Comment: Align code formatting when you are adding in the question.

Comment: I have not added those because it has the same issue on IE. The  image with id="Bubble" is working for IE onclick of which the div with id="botchat" should be displayed. So we can leave the other two functions for IE.

Comment: do not add "javascript:" label inside of onclick

Answer (score -1):

After formatting your code I have found that you have missed myFunction() and closeFunction() in your code.

Paste your code for those functions.

```js
 function myChat() {
        var a = document.getElementById("botchat");
        var b = document.getElementById("chat-header");
        var c = document.getElementById("body");
        document.getElementById("Bubble").style.display = "none";
        if (a.style.display == "block") { a.style.display = "none"; } else { a.style.display = "block"; }
        if (b.style.display == "block") { b.style.display = "none"; } else { b.style.display = "block"; }
        c.style.height = "100vh"; c.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-bubble" id="chat-bubble">
    <div id="chat-header">
        <img src="images/Chatbot-icon.png" id="chat-icon">
        <span> YODA </ span>
            <img src="images/close.png" id="close-icon" onClick="closeFunction();"> </div>
    <div id="webchat" role="main" class="webchat"></div>
    <div id="botchat" role="main" class="webchat"></div>
    <img src="images/Chatbot-icon.png" id="chatBubble" onClick="myFunction();">
    <img src="images/Chatbot-icon.png" id="Bubble" onmousedown="myChat();">
</div>
```